# Correct syntax for writing NativeScript plugin

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I'm learning about NativeScript plugins and am trying to get the PubNub iOS SDK working. So far (with the TypeScript below), I am able to successfully configure, subscribe to channels, and publish messages. I'm trying to receive messages as well by converting the "// Handle new message..." section to TypeScript as well, but haven't been able to get it working. How would I write this?

Objective-C:

```
// Initialize and configure PubNub client instance
PNConfiguration *configuration = [PNConfiguration configurationWithPublishKey:@"demo" subscribeKey:@"demo"];
self.client = [PubNub clientWithConfiguration:configuration];
[self.client addListener:self];

// Subscribe to demo channel with presence observation
[self.client subscribeToChannels: @[@"my_channel"] withPresence:YES];

// Handle new message from one of channels on which client has been subscribed.
- (void)client:(PubNub *)client didReceiveMessage:(PNMessageResult *)message {
    NSLog(@"Received message");
}

// Publish message
[self.client publish: @{@"message": @"this is my message"} 
           toChannel: @"my_channel" withCompletion:^(PNPublishStatus *status) {
}];
```

Typescript:

```
// Initialize and configure PubNub client instance
this.config = PNConfiguration.configurationWithPublishKeySubscribeKey("demo", "demo");
this.client = PubNub.clientWithConfiguration(this.config);
this.client.addListener();

// Subscribe to demo channel with presence observation
this.client.subscribeToChannelsWithPresence(channels, true);

// Handle new message from one of channels on which client has been subscribed. 
   ?

// Publish message
this.client.publishToChannelWithCompletion(msgObj, channel, function(publishStatus) {
  console.log(publishStatus.data)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the `PNObjectEventListener` delegate here. You should implement the delegate and pass it's instance to `addListener` function for the `didReceiveMessage` callback to be invoked upon a new message.

For example [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/ui/text-view/text-view.ios.ts#L15-L96) you can see how the core framework implements UITextViewDelegate for TextView so it could be notified upon changes and other events.

Since you are using TypeScript, take advantage of [typings](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/Use-Native-iOS-Libraries#troubleshooting) for your PubNub library so it may be easy for you to get find the right syntax.

Comment: Ah I see, the example made it clear, I was able to create a delegate with the PNObjectEventListener protocol and pass that instance to addListener like you said, then use the clientDidReceiveMessage callback to get & pass the message back to the owner successfully